# a method to prevent duplicate entry in multiline textbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So I try to write a a code to prevent duplicated entry from register at all. So I've tried this but it doesn't work like how I want it to.

```
Private Sub NoDuplicate1()
    For Each line As String In Me.TxtResult4.Text.Split(vbLf)
        If line = TxtResult4.Text Then
            LblMsg.Text = ""
            TxtResult4.Text = TxtResult4.Text.Remove(TxtResult4.Text.LastIndexOf(Environment.NewLine))


        End If

    Next
End Sub
```

I've also try this code and put in postback and it work:

```
 If Not IsPostBack Then

        TxtResult3.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                       TxtResult3.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Distinct())
        TxtResult4.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                       TxtResult4.Text.Split({Environment.NewLine}, StringSplitOptions.None).Distinct())

End If
```

but the problem that I have with the code is that the duplicate data only deleted when the page refresh. when what I want to do is to block/prevent the duplicate data from being enter at all . Is there any suggestion on how I can modified my code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should remove any duplicate lines in the TextBox.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim splitter() As String = {Environment.NewLine}
    Dim lines() As String = TextBox1.Text.Split(splitter, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    Dim dupFree = lines.Distinct.ToArray
    TextBox1.Text = Join(dupFree, Environment.NewLine)
End Sub
```